# Input field validation for Email

Tags: html, angularjs, validation

I have the following HTML code. The validation takes place as soon as I start typing, i.e. as long as the string is not a valid email adddress, the error message is displayed. However, I want it to be displayed once the input field is out of focus and I go on to another input field for example. Is that possible even?

```
<div>
  <label>Mail</label><br>
  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Mail Address"
     ng-model="emailAddress" required>
  <span style="color:red;font-family:Open Sans;font-weight: 400;font-size: 14px" ng-show="form.email.$dirty && form.email.$invalid"></span>
  <span ng-show="form.email.$error.required">Email is required.</span>
  <span ng-show="form.email.$error.email">Invalid email address.</span>                
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$touched`.

```
<div>
  <label>Mail</label><br>
  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Mail Address"
     ng-model="emailAddress" required>
  <span style="color:red;font-family:Open Sans;font-weight: 400;font-size: 14px" ng-show="form.email.$dirty && form.email.$invalid"></span>
  <span ng-show="form.email.$error.required && form.email.$touched">Email is required.</span>
  <span ng-show="form.email.$error.email && form.email.$touched">Invalid email address.</span>                
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Angular 1.3 introduced the $touched property. When you touch and leave the input (input lost the focus) the $touched value switch to **true**.

> @property {boolean} $untouched True if control has not lost focus yet.
>
> @property {boolean} $touched True if control has lost focus.
>
> @property {boolean} $pristine True if user has not interacted with the control yet.
>
> @property {boolean} $dirty True if user has already interacted with the control.

```
<div>
  <label>Mail</label><br>
  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Mail Address"
     ng-model="emailAddress" required>
  <span style="color:red;font-family:Open Sans;font-weight: 400;font-size: 14px" ng-show="form.email.$dirty && form.email.$invalid"></span>
  <span ng-show="form.email.$error.required && form.email.$touched">Email is required.</span>
  <span ng-show="form.email.$error.email && form.email.$touched">Invalid email address.</span>    
</div>
```